# Save data to server using BackboneJS

Tags: backbone.js

I am very new to BackboneJS. I am creating a simple CRUD application using BackboneJS.

I have seen an example on the web (http://backbonetutorials.com/videos/beginner/). I can see a GET request on load of application i.e. http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users to get all the users in JSON format.

I just wanted to know what is this url (http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users).

Can someone help me to understand where and how data is getting saved?

What do I need to do, if I want to do the same thing on my localhost?
Do I need to write any server side code in order for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

The url in the example is (one of) the API endpoints that the demo application interacts with in order to function.  Backbone.JS will allow you to fetch and save data in many different ways (by writing a connector yourself) but the default means of getting and setting Model data for backbone is through AJAX calls to a [RESTful API](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html).

So lets take a look at this code snippet:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

MyModelCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: '/myserver/api'
});
```

Note the "url" configuration option on the Collection.  That is the URL that Backbone will make calls to (GET,POST and others) in order to get and set data for the application.  That URL should be provided by **you** in most cases - *especially* if you are the one building the application.

So in short...yes, you will need to write some server side code for your CRUD application to work.  I would suggest watching the REST tutorial I linked above and then consulting these articles which provide a bit more detail about how Backbone models are supposed to work.

[What is a Model](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/)

[Collection URL option](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url)

[Model URL option](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url)

[Backbone Model - Save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

Comment: I have gone though it and what i understood that server side code we can write in JS with a combination of NodeJS & MangoDB. Can i use any other server side language (Java,PHP etc.) & any other DB (Oracle, MySQL etc.) with BackboneJS application ?

Please help me to understand.

Comment: Yes you can use any back end storage (Mongo, Postgresql, Mysql, etc) and any server side language (Java, PHP, Node.JS, Ruby, Perl, the list goes on) that can be served by an HTTP server to create a RESTful interface.  If you are creating this yourself and do not have much experience I suggest you choose something easy to setup and that you will enjoy learning.  Perhaps PHP and MySQL because then you could use (WAMP) http://www.wampserver.com/en/ or (XAMPP) https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html to get started developing on your local machine with relatively little time spent on setup.

Answer (score 0):

The server side code is needed.

But if you just want some data not matter they are real or fake. What don't you just create a object with fake data and set the `Model` or `Collection` with them. This is more easier than setting up a backend.